# How to transfer api alongside server for saving in DB , Ajax to C#

Tags: json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm totally confused,
I got an API that I needed to display client-side data that I managed, and save it to the server side.

I am totally in trouble but can I get to the server side and pass it the data I can keep in a database?

displayRepos- show the repos

API- "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" +name of repository

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GitHub Repos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="serachRepositories">
        <label>GitHub repositories name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="repositories" />
        <button onclick="loadRepos()">Load Repos</button>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Repository Name</th>
            <th>Photo of user</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>link</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="repos" >

        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script>
        function loadRepos() {
            $("#repos").empty();
            let url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" +$("#repositories").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: displayRepos,
                error: displayError
            });
            function displayRepos(respos) {
                var sTxt = '';
                for (let repo of respos.items) {
                    sTxt += '<tr>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' +  repo.name+'</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' +'<img src='+repo.owner['avatar_url']+' height="42" width="42">' + '</td>';
                    sTxt += '<td>' + repo.owner['login'] + '</td>'; 
                    sTxt += '<td>' + '<a href='+repo.html_url+'>'+repo.full_name +'</a>'+ '</td>';
                    sTxt += '</tr>';
                }
                $('#repos').append(sTxt);
            }
            function displayError(err) {
                $("#repos").append($("<li>Error</li>"));
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are lots of different way to interact with DBs in .NET- Entity Framework is very popular and often used for small applications. I'd suggest looking into it. You can send data to your MVC controller via ajax (or form post) then save the data to your db once your controller has received it. Breaking apart the problem into smaller parts will help you. Once you have attempted writing some code to solve your issue, I'm sure the folks here on SO will be of much more help solving your issue. As it stands now, I don't see any code making an attempt to do what you're asking

Comment: @GergH Thanks for answer, but i really don't understand how to reach server side
from client side and send data to server.